# How can content placeholder be implemented in Android RecyclerView just like it is in Facebook?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want a content placeholder for my `TextView`s in a `RecyclerView` until the data is fetched & parsed from the server.

By content placeholder, I don't mean default text or a text saying no results. Please look how Facebook displays gray colored animated blocks before displaying the actual data on the web. I want to achieve that.

Basically a kind of loader unless my data is ready to be displayed (*please don't suggest me with horizontal or spinning loaders*).
e.g.: I display a gray colored block and as soon as my data is ready to be displayed I'll remove the block and then display the text.

All of that needs to be done in a `RecyclerView`. I hope I am clear with my need.

How do I achieve this?

1. I can't place dummy views in the `RecyclerView` because, unless I have the data my `getCount` will return 0 so no views will be displayed.
2. I don't want to display a dummy layout and then make it gone when I get the actual data, that doesn't look clean.

Comment: add hint in textview

Comment: you can also add default text in xml

Comment: I don't want it this. I want placeholders into which my text will load. Have you observed how it is in facebook? That way.
Say some blocks display & then when content is ready it is displayed into it.

Comment: IWell, I don't want default text. I said I want it similar to facebook. Please have a look at how facebook data loads.

Comment: can you explain more i didnt understand .what exactly you want. put image of facebook which you want to do like it.

Comment: so use something like `android.widget.ViewSwitcher` or similar view as a `RecyclerView`'s item

Comment: You can create some dummy items till you get the data from server and you can put a GIF or create  animation like facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly Facebook's implementation I assume they load an initial data source with "lean" data from which you can tell how many units you will need to display, based on that you could create a placeholder (that would be a type in your `RecyclerView`), once the full data for that placeholder was loaded you notify data set change and replace the placeholder with the full item (again another type in your `RecyclerView`).

> Basically a kind of loader unless my data is ready to be displayed

If you have absolutely no data, for example you don't have the amount of "blocks" that will be displayed you can't display a placeholder as it might be discarded if you have an empty data set returned from your data source.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea. I too thought of something similar. Will start implementing now. :)

Answer (score 0):

this should work,

```
<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="No Results" />
```

The *id* does the trick!

You have to be using a ListViewActivity for it to work!

**If not extending ListViewActivity**

try,

ListView.setEmptyView() [read here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: I don't want it this. I want placeholders into which my text will load. Have you observed how it is in facebook? That way.
Say some blocks display & then when content is ready it is displayed into it.

Comment: Ohh! Sorry! I didn't read properly in a hurry. I'll try this.

Comment: I am using an AppCompatActivity & a RecyclerView.
I can't change it. The full app uses this in many palces.

Comment: try without using the ListViewActivity, if it doesn't work, there are other ways to do it

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari so decide: so you want it in a `ListView` or `RecylerView`? also i think nobody is quite sure what you want to achieve actually...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the skeleton layout and inflate it on the whole screen. Then you can use different libraries to add the shimmer effect.

drawable/skeleton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <solid android:color="@color/skeleton"/>
<corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

layout/skeleton_row_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/row_layout_height">

  <View
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/skeleton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

  <View
    android:id="@+id/topText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/icon"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/skeleton"/>

  <View
    android:id="@+id/bottomText"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topText"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/skeleton"/>

  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/skeleton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In this tutorial I wrote you will find how to replace the skeleton with the recyclerView: https://medium.com/@sha17187/upgrade-progress-loading-with-a-skeleton-and-shimmer-effect-in-android-863ea4ff5b0b

Comment: I think it might be good if you'd explicitly disclose that you are the author of that blog post. It might get viewed as illegitimate self-promotion otherwise (I'm not saying it is). Maybe you'd like to have a look at the last section here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior

Comment: It answers the question and is very detailed there, I added that I wrote the tutorial. Thank you